# Sampling with replacement a matrix element from a list in R

Tags: r, matrix, replace, sample

Here I am generating a list of matrix objects.

```
c<-11
l<-10
v<-list()
p<-100

for(i in 1:p) {
m<-matrix(sample(c(-1,1),l*c,replace=TRUE),l,c)
v[[i]]<-m
}
```

At this point, I am trying to randomly sample with replacement a matrix element from the list vector 'v'.

```
sample(v,size=11,replace=TRUE)
```

But this sample function returns the first 11 elements, instead of randomly selecting from the 100 elements in 'v'.

First, how do I randomly select matrix objects from 'v' and store those random samples in a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to sample from each element of the `list` 'v' use `sapply` to loop over the `list`

```
out <- sapply(v, function(x) sample(x, size = 11, replace = TRUE))
```

---

or if you want to sample 11 `list` elements, `sample` from the sequence of `list`, and use that index to extract the `list` elements

```
out <- v[sample(seq_along(v), 11, replace = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you could sample the index

```
v[sample(1:p,size = c,replace = TRUE)]
```